# Java Log Manager overriding default values by passing properties while running java code

Tags: java, java.util.logging

Is there a way to override LogManager's configuration in java by passing command line property while launching application.
Currently I pass these property to LogManager using

```
File fn = new File(filename);
URL url = fn.toURI().toURL();
LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(url.openStream())

filename contains this

handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.level = CONFIG

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = ALL
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = abc.common.util.LogFormatter

java.util.logging.FileHandler.level = ALL
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = abc.common.util.LogFormatter
```

I cannot change file but I need to change .level = CONFIG to some other value. I cann't change code but can only pass java properties while launching application.

Is it possible to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a new config location from the command line using -

```
 java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=<filelocation>
```

Comment: Good point.  However, the java.util.logging.config.file argument only modifies the behavior of the no argument LogManager.readConfiguration method.  The example is using LogManager.readConfiguration(InputStream) method which does not look for that system property.

Comment: I was checking the code and it calls a reset, so your right this wont work. Frustrating! Could you create a custom version of the class, and precede it in the classpath?

Comment: Agreed.  This is starting to sound like an answer I read somewhere else. :)

Answer (score 1):

Given your restrictions the only command line argument of use is [java.util.logging.manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html) system property.  You would then have to modify the classpath argument to include custom log manager perform the steps you require.

Alternatively, if your goal is to just change the root logger level you can attach [JConsole](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/index.html#jconsole) to the running application and use it to override the current settings.  In the MBeans tab, go to java.util.logging->Logging->Operations->setLoggerLevel.  Delete all characters the 'p0' field and enter the level name in upper case or the level number in 'p1' field.  Click setLoggerLevel to update the level.